# Recognize Morse-like code words

Tags: arduino-uno

In a line there're voltage levels representing words of dots and dashes. In particular, the device is intended to raise an output each time a given pattern of five short/long signals (say 1s and 2s durations, respectively) is recognized (and restart if nothing comes in for a given time). A sort of Morse code recognizer (Arduino Uno preferred, but others are also OK) would be a good starting point. Any hint is welcome, I'm new in this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a GPIO of an Arduino and check (at the speed you need) the HIGH/LOW state.

Depending on the speed at which is sent, you can check the dots and dashes being sent, e.g. by keeping a timer since the last change checking if it is a short or long 'HIGH'.

You have to sample often enough to check if there is a drop (between dots/dashes).

Comment: Is Arduino Uno the best selection to implement this device? Since it's going to be embedded (the smallest, the better), I would like to know the best fitting option.

Comment: There are many microcontrollers. Arduino is not the smallest or cheapest, but probably the easiest to program, especially if you are new to microcontrollers). There are smaller, like Arduino micro/nano etc, which also are not difficult to program. 

There are also other (small) microcontrollers, even cheaper, but mostly those have a more steep learning curve, like PIC, STM8/32.